# See source code on dashboard.heroku.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is there any way to see my rails app right from heroku page? like you can doit from BitBucket for example?

I've been searching around and I can't find anything

Thanks in advance! I'm leaving an image of how i see it from BitBucket!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess not, but you can clone it by this command :

```
git clone git@heroku.com:your_app_name.git
```

also you can check your application logs if anything went wrong by typing `heroku logs` in your terminal

Comment: @Jesus Gutierrez have you find another answer to your question ?

Comment: No. I didn't. I hope they notice this lack soon.

Comment: well, you cannot browser your app on heroku you already have it on your local or github no need to browse it form heroku.

Answer (score 2):

That's not posible right now, but that's a great idea. Why don't you tell them what you want in the contact page. You'd be feedbacking them. I'm sure every one will appretiate this.

https://www.heroku.com/contact

Answer (score 1):

Nope, heroku does not give you a gui for your app. Closest thing would be...

$ heroku run bash

Which gives you a unixish command line to work from.